# How to fix corrupted windows files and registry without reinstalling

Tags: windows

My windows 11 machine has suffered a great deal of system file and registry corruptions making it act funny. I have my installation media ready and can reinstall windows but i dont want to take such drastic step in order to avoid having to reinstall a lot of programs. How can i repair my sytem files from the installation media without reinstalling windows.

Comment: Run `dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` and `SFC /SCANNOW` to repair the system files, but if your registry is corrupted, nothing short of a full clean install will solve that problem.

Comment: DISM check health really takes a long time eh

Comment: It's faster then reinstalling Windows for potentially no reason, of course without specifics on HOW windows is corrupt, I can't indicate if running that command will even solve any of your issues.  It shouldn't take that long, we should be talking minutes, instead of an hour.

Comment: It shouldn't take that long, unless your setup is really in bad shape. Windows 11 is still quite unstable. If you can go back to Windows 10, I recommend doing just that.

Comment: My dism restore health is stuck at 62.3%, any ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: You need to proceed with the Repair Install (or Fresh Install) as I noted in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Making changes to the registry can damage Windows to the point it needs to be fully reinstalled (Windows 7, 8, 10, and 11).

Try first a Windows 11 Repair Install.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

Use the appropriate link to create a Windows 11 USB Key (you need a 16 GB Key available). Run it, create the Key (it takes a few minutes).

Then (when done) exit the window to create the key, open Windows File Explorer and navigate to the key.

See setup.exe on the Key. Run Setup. Windows 11 Repair begins.

Start with the option to Keep Everything.

I have run the Windows 11 Repair on my Windows 11 Insider machine and it worked just fine.

======

If Windows Repair does not work (and some registry damage may prevent it from working), then you must back up and reinstall Windows.

Comment: this repair install does seem like the best solution, will try this thanks so much

Comment: Good. And as noted, if that does not work. a fresh install may be the only answer as I noted in my answer above